# There is a column having 177 category i want to keep categories having top 10 value counts and replace the rest of them by unknown

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

There is column having 177 different categories where count of categories vary from 270  to 1. I want to keep the categories having top 10 value counts and replace the rest of them with unknown.
How am I supposed to do that in python.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  “Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: Each step you describe is documented quite well in existing tutorials, so it's not clear where you're stuck.  Also see Stack Overflow guidance on [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Simply dumping your assignment here is unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't that clear what you are after, or what your data looks like, but assuming you have a dataframe named `df`. Something like this would work:

```
top_ten_categories = df['category'].value_counts().head(10).index.to_list()
df['category'] = np.where(df['category'].isin(top_ten_categories),df['category'], 'Unknown')
```